# Child regex pattern in variable

Tags: c#, regex

Can a regex consist of child patterns (not value) in some variables so for example if I have following regex:-

"\d+X\d+" which can capture values like 7X4, is it possible to assign \d+ in some sort of variable and specify that variable in place of second \d+. Note that I am not talking about back-reference which will match the captured value rather than the pattern.

Comment: You are most likely looking for subroutines.

Comment: C# regex does not support recursion. You can build the pattern dynamically.

Comment: It seems so but I think subroutines are not available in C# which I am using. Thanks for the suggestion though.